# How to get place ids from address_components using google api for web?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How to get place ids from address_components using google api for web? Is it possible to get the id of the titles?

Comment: what is your code for retrieving the addresses is it geo location search?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '#s', function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            googleMapsLoaded();
        }, 300);
    });
});
var autocomplete;
function initialize() {
    var options = {
       types : ['(regions)']
    };
    var input = document.getElementById('s');
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input , options, googleMapsLoaded);
}
var map = google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function googleMapsLoaded(){
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    console.log(place);
}`

Comment: have you checked if it is in place.place_id
or place.[0].place_id

var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
console.log(place.place_id);
console.log(place.[o].place_id);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get place\_id of address\_components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499392/get-place-id-of-address-components)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '#s', function () { 
       window.setTimeout(function () {
       googleMapsLoaded(); }, 300); 
    }); 
}); 

var autocomplete; function initialize() { 
var options = { 
   types : ['(regions)'] }; 
   var input = document.getElementById('s'); 
   autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input , options, googleMapsLoaded); 
} 

var map = google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);         

function googleMapsLoaded(){
   var place = autocomplete.getPlace(); 
   console.log(place.place_id); 
}
```